# One `Using` statement per script?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm working on writing some scripts and utilizing new features to make them easier to understand now that I'm unbound from my `PSv2` chains.  In this scenario, I have a number of types I'm using that I want to reduce the overhead on by importing the namespace like you would in `C#`.

Let me start this off by saying I know about:

```
. ([scriptblock]::Create('Using Namespace Example.Namespace'))
```

This *works*, but I want my scripts to be cleaner without using workarounds. The `using` statement must be the first uncommented line in a script, and when I tried to comma-separate namespaces, it gave me errors as it was trying to combine them all into one string (even if I delimited them with quotes, or included quotes at all, for that matter).  This feature isn't very well documented, so I'm hoping someone else has more insight from experience.

My question: does the `using` statement support multiple namespaces or modules from a script?

Comment: You can use multiple `using` statements per script.

Comment: @PetSerAl How? When I tried to use multiple statements, script analyzer instantly threw errors and the script wouldn't execute.

Comment: If you have error, then show it. https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/v7Q4My9dIS8xN7W4IDE5VSG4srgkNVfPJzOv0FoBh6RLYkkiFxcenXquFQVFqcXFmfl5xVxc0a55pbmpRYlJOamxem6lOTl@QD1c0SBTQtAFERqRRP//BwA

Comment: @PetSerAl After restarting my editor, it now works.. Previously, it was throwing errors about the `using` statement not being the first line when I would use multiple `using` lines and script analyzer was flagging it as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it would turn out, editors are not perfect.  There is not a limit to `Using` statements as long as they are the first non-comment statements in your script and contiguous.

Example usage:

```
#Requires -Version 5
Using Namespace System.Net
Using Namespace System.Net.Sockets
Using Module MyModule # this assumes MyModule is in the $Env:PSModulePath

[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

[TcpClient]::new().
  Connect(
    @([Dns]::GetHostEntry('localhost').AddressList)[0],
    5985
  )

[MyClass].FullName
```